# How do I install an app in xcode (iOS) simulator manually

Tags: ios, xcode6, coronasdk, ios8.1

I have an iOS Universal app built using Corona Simulator. I want screenshots of the app in Xcode Simulator. How do I install the app in the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build the app with Corona Simulator (File > Build > iOS), select the option: Build for: Xcode simulator.

It will generate the binary and will launch the game directly in xcode simulator, where you can take screenshots etc

Comment: After building for xCode simulator, there is a dialog that says it is going to open up in the simulator. But, nothing really happens. In MacOS 10.10, the location of the simulator has changed. Also, each simulator has its own guid.

Comment: Hmm, for me it works, I have xcode 5.1... What happens is the simulator is directly launched, you cannot compile the mac sources or anything, it just launches straight away.
Do you have the latest corona version ?

Comment: I have the Xcode 6 and latest corona version (public release). Even distribute to AppStore is failing.

Comment: It might be a corona issue then, maybe open a ticket on corona's support center ?

Comment: It is a Corona issue. The Corona team have advised that they have fix for this in the next public release.